# Максимальный объем byte[] для передачи на веб-сервис

Tags: c#

Есть метод веб-сервиса, один из параметров метода - строка, которая используется для передачи `byte[]`.

```
file = Convert.ToBase64String(fileByteArray);
```

При больших размерах файлов очень часто возникает ошибка в том что не получается потом собрать исходный файл (либо ошибка при передаче по протоколу HTTP, либо возможно есть ограничение на размер строки).

Как лучше всего поступить в данном случае, спасибо

Comment: в сервисе в web.config есть параметры для конретного биндинга

Comment: Есть такой подход как потоковая модель построения сервисов - суть в том что , если большие данные , то сервер отдаёт их в нескольких потоков , т.е вы отправляете запрос сервер вернёт ответ с частью данных , а потом пришлёт несколько запросов с другими частьями данных.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не написали используемые технологии и какая конкретно ошибка выводится, поэтому можно дать только общий ответ. В зависимости от ситуации, могут влиять разные ограничения, например:

При использовании WCF - параметр maxReceivedMessageSize (по умолчанию - 65536 байт), задается на сервере и на клиенте:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize = "1000000">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```

При размещении службы (WCF или ASMX) в IIS - параметры executionTimeout (по умолчанию 110 seconds) и maxRequestLength (по умолчанию 4096 KB):

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

Также, если размер файла настолько велик, что превышает доступную память на сервере, нужно смотреть в сторону [WCF Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx#Streaming%20Data)